# stop bold in algorithmx

Tags: bold, algorithmicx

I am using the algorithmx package:

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf

The keywords such as "if", "while", "then", "else" "end if" etc. etc.  all appear in bold font.  I am looking for an easy "switch" to turn off the bold font "feature" of this package.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (I suggest contacting the package author to customize this as a new package feature).

Take [`algpseudocode`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty), for example. All the keywords are defined verbatim as `\textbf{<keyword>}`:

```
%
%      ***      KEYWORDS      ***
%
\algnewcommand\algorithmicend{\textbf{end}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicdo{\textbf{do}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\textbf{while}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{for}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{for all}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicloop{\textbf{loop}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicrepeat{\textbf{repeat}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicuntil{\textbf{until}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\textbf{procedure}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\textbf{function}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicif{\textbf{if}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicthen{\textbf{then}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicelse{\textbf{else}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Require:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Ensure:}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{return}}
\algnewcommand\textproc{\textsc}
```

You would have to redefine these to suit your needs in a very generic way. Alternatively, if you're willing to sacrifice *all* `\textbf` usages within the `algorithmic` environment, you can make `\textbf` a no-op by adding to your document preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\let\textbf\relax}
```

Here is a minimal example showing the output with the above change:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\let\textbf\relax}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d.\ of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
        \State $a\gets b$
        \State $b\gets r$
        \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

This is what the output would have looked like without the no-op addition/patch using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]